# Error al crear proyecto nuevo de Angular cli npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

de ante mano muchas gracias por su ayuda, estoy comenzando a aprender Angular y al momento de crear un nuevo proyecto con el comando "ng new nuevoProyecto" antes de finalizar me marca algunos errores y dice que se corto inesperadamente el proceso, e instalado de nuevo npm y usado el nvm para instalar una version mas reciente en este momento estoy usando la 14.2, ademas de eso cuando hago un npm test me marca errores también, uso linux mint, si alguien tiene idea de como solucionar esto le agradezco muchisimo su ayuda.

Error al crear proyecto nuevo de Angular:

> CREATE tertertertre/e2e/src/app.po.ts (301 bytes)
> ⠇ Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
> npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...://registry.npmjs.org'

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

> npm ERR!     /home/artrockrs/.npm/_logs/2020-05-13T21_02_29_186Z-debug.log

> ✖ Package install failed, see above.
> The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

Comment: Intenta con `npm update`. Que version de `node` tienes y de `angular-cli`?

Comment: Ya intente "npm update" aun persisten el problema, tengo node v12.16.3 y Angular CLI: 9.1.5

Comment: Que terminal estas usando?

Comment: estoy usando bash.

Answer (score 3):

Ufff luego de trastear 2 días logre solucionar mi problema, lo encontré en stackoverflow en ingles, la solucion que me funciono fue actualizar npm y luego forzar el limpiado del cache de npm con el siguiente código:

`npm cache clean --force`

Posterior a esto pude ejecutar sin problema la creación de mi proyecto angular.

Dejo el link de la publicación original:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387743/npm-err-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-registry-npmjs-org

Gracias a los que se tomaron el tiempo de leer mi consulta.

Comment: Sería muy genial si traduces la respuesta del enlace, así la comunidad en español se beneficia, preservamos el conocimiento y de seguro te llevas algunos votos, solo deja el enlace como crédito al autor.

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta para dejarla mucho mas clara, gracias por la observación.